# Mounting another hard drive to a HP Envy h8-1414?

Tags: hard-drive, computer-building

[image]I've got an HP Envy h8-1414 with two hard drives already installed in it.  I have a third drive I need to use to store backups on and I can't find any places where I can jam another harddrive in although the motherboard does appear to support more hard drives.

The only place I can think of is the empty DVD bay just below it.  I'd like to put one of those removable bays in there, but I'm having a hard time finding a good cooled one online, are towers so unpopular now that they have stopped making them?

Comment: Your 'problem' is probably that its a crappy matx case (and they're generally *that* small(You actually have a drive bay, some don't!) and they assume you don't need all those drives. That and Andrew is likely to get mad at you ;p.

Comment: I am that Andrew... ;)

Comment: I wonder if the drive would fit in that bay under the 2 5 1/4 inch bays I see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a 3.5 to 5.25 adaptor. There are several around the net, depends where you live for deivery. Here is a sample from newegg.com. It states that you cann attach a fan if you like.[adaptor for drive](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817997036)